# Should child entity classes have their own repositories?

Tags: orm, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, domain-object

I have several classes inheriting from an `Admin` class: `Manager`, `Translator`, etc.

`Admin` is an aggregate, so should have its own *Repository*. However, some methods to find Managers or Translators might be specific to these classes. Others might be common to all Admins.

What is the best practice here? Should I:

- put all the methods to find Admins in one Repository?
- or mimic the hierarchy of domain model classes with a hierarchy of Repositories, then having a `ManagerRepository` and a `TranslatorRepository` extending an `AdminRepository`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see - it doesn't matter that much.

I would stick with one `AdminRepository` unless it bloats and begs for decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, only aggregate roots require their own repositories.

In case you need to manage a particular entity without accessing another aggregate root, then that entity can be considered (but not necessarily) an aggregate root itself.

So I'd say: pick your business/domain viewpoint, then draw your technical conclusions.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm unsure whether you understood the question correctly: Admin is an aggregate root, and its subclasses Manager and Translator are (therefore?) aggregates as well. The question is not whether I should consider them as aggregates, but rather whether they should share one *Repository* or all of them have a Repository.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My thinking on this is: if you want to do the exact same operations on Manager and Translator, so if by and large they are equal citizens, then it would make sense to have a single Repository. If they require different handling or different operations, then I think a separate Repository for each would be best. Just my 2 cents...